# Rewriting font path for dist with Grunt

Tags: fonts, gruntjs, font-awesome

I have currently installed the Font-Awesome Bower package in my project and imported the scss-file into my own stylesheet.

I currently reference the path for the fonts in my scss-file with the following override of the default path:

```
$icon-font-path: "../bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/";
```

... which works great when serving the development version. When building (to dist), I copy the fonts to a `/fonts` directory. However, this is where I run into problems. My CSS obviously still uses the path I showed above, and the fonts can't be found. So my question is, how can I have my current path in the dev environment but make sure the path is rewritten to `fonts/` when building?

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem these days. By comparing different version of yo webapp Gruntfile.js files. I found if you put below code in, then font-awesome will works.

copy:{

dist:{
       ...,

```
   {
        expand: true,
        dot: true,
        cwd: 'bower_components/font-awesome/',
        src: 'fonts/*',
        dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
    }
```

}

copy:dist copy 5 font-awesome font files to the dist/fonts directory. While in development mode, bower_components/font-awesome/ directory is directly referenced, so there is no problem.

**Update:**

Wait, maybe you already did that. And I found in my main.scss, the awesome-font path is:

$icon-font-path: "../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";

**$fa-font-path:** "../bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/";